# Is Github Actions available on forked repositories?

Tags: github-actions

I forked [watchman](https://github.com/gmatheu/watchman) repository and I want to add some steps to its `main.workflow` (the goal is to publish artifacts to create a snap package).

But I'm not able to see the `Actions` tab in the repository.

**Are there any additional steps to configure Github Actions available on a forked repository?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No further actions are required, as long you or your organization is signed into [beta](https://github.com/features/actions). You should see Actions running on next push to fork, or however workflows are set. It's also often suggested to commit changes to workflow file(s) in your fork (editing those coming from upstream or adding your own).

If it takes too long, you can always report it on [Actions forum](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/bd-p/actions); i've seen a few threads about exactly same problem in last weeks, with GitHub staff fixing it manually.

Comment: Adding a commit did the trick (Actions tab appeared). There was a warning message about forked repositories, but it allows you to enable it.

Answer (score 11):

> I'm not able to see the Actions tab in the repository.

Update August 2020, 10 months later, see:

> ## [GitHub Actions improvements for fork and pull request workflows](https://github.blog/2020-08-03-github-actions-improvements-for-fork-and-pull-request-workflows/)
>
> <sup>written by **[Chris Patterson](https://github.com/chrispat)**</sup>
>
> ### New settings for private repository forks
>
> [...] To enable these users to run workflows on fork pull requests, we’ve introduced three new settings at the enterprise, organization, and repository level for private repositories only.
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/185122/88571581-de3d5300-d00b-11ea-8d8c-027e951d63e1.png?ssl=1]
>
> ### Improvements for public repository forks
>
> [...] we’ve added a new **`pull_request_target`** event, which behaves in an almost identical way to the `pull_request` event with the same set of filters and payload.
>
> However, instead of running against the workflow and code from the merge commit, the event runs against the workflow and code from the ***base*** of the pull request.
> This means the workflow is running from a trusted source and is given access to a read/write token as well as secrets enabling the maintainer to safely comment on or label a pull request.
> This event can be used in combination with the private repository settings as well.